# Django-Registration override Registration Form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration

I'm using Django-Registration 2.3 for a project and trying to override the standard RegistrationForm with the following:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    captcha = NoReCaptchaField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
        widgets = {
            'first_name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'last_name' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'username' : forms.HiddenInput(),
            'email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'password1' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
            'password2' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}),
        }
```

I'm then calling this from my urls.py with `url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=MyRegistrationForm), name='registration_register'),`

In the template the `captcha`, `first_name` and `last_name` fields are rendered using form-control, the `username` is hidden but the other fields are rendered without the class.  What do I need to do?

Comment: You can't use `widgets` to override fields that are declared explicitly by the form. See the [note](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) in the docs. In your case, `email` is declared by `RegistrationForm`, and `password1` and `password2` are declared by `UserCreationForm` (which `RegistrationForm` subclasses). Therefore these three fields can't be overridden by `widgets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem once and i used this

```
class MyRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    captcha = NoReCaptchaField()
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                                                            'name': "password1",
                                                                                            'type': "password"}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
                                                                                            'name': "password2",
                                                                                            'type': "password"}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
        widgets = {
            'username' : forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Comment: some fields cant be changed they have a defualt attr